# Python index with s, d, b, c, o, x, X, n, etc... what are they?

Tags: python, indexing

I did not realize that Python indexes can have characters and not just integers.

I was looking at this Tensorflow tutorial for RNN text generation:  [RNN text generation TF 2.0](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r2/tutorials/text/text_generation.ipynb#scrollTo=FYyNlCNXymwY)

In the second cell after section title "Process the Text" it has this code:

```
print('{')
for char,_ in zip(char2idx, range(20)):
    print('  {:4s}: {:3d},'.format(repr(char), char2idx[char]))
    print('  {:4s}: {:2d},'.format(repr(char), char2idx[char]))#repr compute official string rep of an object
print('  ...\n}')
```

I played around with the integers in front of `s` and `d` and noticed they have something to do with spacing and alignment.  But I came up empty handed on my search for the definitions of how and when to use these.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings is the full reference

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for pointing in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't indexes, they're format specifiers. `s` means "string" and `d` means "decimal number". The numbers in front indicate how much whitespace to use for alignment. These are defined in the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). The letters are "type"s and the numbers are "width"s.

Comment: yes, I was just pouring over the link provided by user2357112:  "Replacing %x and %o and converting the value to different bases:'  `>>> "int: {0:d};  hex: {0:x};  oct: {0:o};  bin: {0:b}".format(42)
'int: 42;  hex: 2a;  oct: 52;  bin: 101010'`

Comment: The available string presentation types are:

Type Meaning
's' String format. This is the default type for strings and may be omitted.
None The same as 's'.